# How to make a flash tag cloud clickable when using href="#"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash

I am new to tag cloud.

I want to display all the tags that returned from server and if anyone clicks on any tag, i would like to display all the blogs which having the tag.

Actually i am able to create tag cloud click-able. But its click-able only when i give h ref like `http://www.google.com`. But i don want to give direct URL in href. If i use `"#"` instead of whole URL, then the tag cloud becomes non-click-able.

Do we have any other option to make the link click-able without giving whole URL.

And also i want to know how to get that `<a>` element in javascript or jquery, when it clicked.

Any suggestions would be appreciative!!!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not clear. Do you need the clicked a tag in flash or in the html page?

***In case you want it in the web page***

You can prevent the navigation to the url specified in the href tag by calling the preventDefault method of the event object passed to the click handler in jquery:

```
$("a").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // prevent from going to the url specified in the href attribute
  // do something with the current a tag
  alert(this.id);
}
```

***In case you want it in flash/actionsript***

Use the [asfunction](http://www.adobe.com/support/flash/action_scripts/actionscript_dictionary/actionscript_dictionary073.html) protocol in the a tag. You can then delegate the asfunction call to a javascript call to get the selected tag into javascript!¨

```
<A HREF="asfunction:linkClicked,Foo">Link</A>
```

You actionscript then must a function called linkClicked, that accepts 1 argument.